# Two values in one byte

Tags: c++, c, hex, bit-manipulation

In a single nibble (0-F) I can store one number from 0 to 15. In one byte, I can store a single number from 0 to 255 (00 - FF).
Can I use a byte (00-FF) to store two different numbers each in the range 0-127 (00 - 7F)?

Comment: In a single byte you can store values from 0 to 255. You are confused by a nibble, four bits, which is often represented as one hexadecimal digit  (number or letter A to F). Two of those digits is a byte.

Comment: I edited my question, thanks

Comment: First of all 4 bit allow to store value from 0 to 15.

Comment: I somewhat like the question. I would bet on no, you can't. To represent two numbers their bits have to be independet of each other. This is only possible when each number has four bits which limits your range to 0-15. But I can understand that one would expect that there is enough space for two 0-127 numbers in the range of 0-255 ;-)

Comment: Back in the days they forced students to understand binary before they were let anywhere near programming...  those were the days.

Comment: And in these days if it doesn't fit in a byte you store it in a double and it doesn't make a difference on your 2TB harddisk or on your 100M connection.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to your question is NO. You *can* split a single byte into two numbers, but the sum of the bits in the two numbers must be <= 8. Since, the range 0-127 requires 7 bits, the other number in the byte can only be 1 bit, i.e. 0-1.

Answer (score 5):

For obvious [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality) reasons, you cannot store two small integers in the 0 ... 127 range in one byte of 0 ... 255 range. In other words the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) [0;127]×[0;127] has 2<sup>14</sup> elements which is bigger than 2<sup>8</sup> (the cardinal of the [0;255] interval, for bytes)

<sup>(If you can afford losing precision - which you didn't tell - you could, e.g. by storing only the highest bits ...)</sup>

Perhaps your question is: could I store two small integers from [0;15] in a byte? Then of course you could:

```
typedef unsigned unibble_t; // unsigned nibble in [0;15]
uint8_t make_from_two_nibbles(unibble_t l, unibble_t r) {
  assert(l<=15);
  assert(r<=15);
  return (l<<4) | r;
}

unibble_t left_nible (uint8_t x) { return x >> 4; }
unibble_t right_nibble (uint8_t) { return x & 0xf; }
```

But I don't think you always should do that. First, you might use bit fields in `struct`. Then (and most importantly) dealing with nibbles that way might be more inefficient and make less readable code than using bytes.

And updating a single nibble, e.g. with

```
void update_left_nibble (uint8_t*p, unibble_t l) {
  assert (p);
  assert (l<=15);
  *p = ((l<<4) | ((*p) & 0xf));
```

}

is sometimes expensive (it involves a memory load and a memory store, so uses the [CPU cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache) and [cache coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence) machinery), and most importantly is generally a non-[atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) operation (what would happen if two different threads are calling simultaneously `update_left_nibble` on the *same* address `p` -i.e. with [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing)- is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

As a rule of thumb, avoid packing more than one data item in a byte unless you are sure it is worthwhile (e.g. you have a billion of such data items).

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use a byte to store two numbers in the range 0-127?

Of course you can:

```
uint8_t storeTwoNumbers(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    return ((a >> 4) & 0x0f) | (b & 0xf0);
}

uint8_t retrieveTwoNumbers(uint8_t byte, unsigned *a, unsigned *b) {
    *b = byte & 0xf0;
    *a = (byte & 0x0f) << 4;
}
```

Numbers are still in range 0...127 (0...255, actually). You just loose some precision, similar to floating point types. Their values increment in steps of 16.

Comment: Same answer as [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33031605/841108), and not what the OP asked. He wants to store two [0;127] numbers in a [0;255] byte

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch If I get you right, you are storing two integers in range 0..15 in one byte. My answer takes the question literally and stores two integers in range 0..127 in one byte. It does so by dropping least significant bits, not most significant as in your answer.

Comment: The OP question  is:  Can I use a byte (00-FF) to store two different numbers each in the range 0-127 (00 - 7F).... So the only short answer is: NO.

Comment: I still find this useful and helped me to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

One byte is not enough for two values in 0…127, because each of those values needs log<sub>2</sub>(128) = 7 bits, for a total of 14, but a byte is only 8 bits.

You can declare variables with bit-packed storage using the C and C++ *bitfield* syntax:

```
struct packed_values {
    uint8_t first : 7;
    uint8_t second : 7;
    uint8_t third : 2;
};
```

In this example, `sizeof(packed_values)` should equal 2 because only 16 bits were used, despite having three fields.

This is simpler than using bitwise arithmetic with `<<` and `&` operators, but it's still not quite the same as ordinary variables: bit-fields have no addresses, so you can't have a pointer (or C++ reference) to one.

Answer (score -1):

You can store two data *in range 0-15* in a single byte, but you should not (one var = one data is a better design).

If you must, you can use bit-masks and bit-shifts to access to the two data in your variable.

```
uint8_t var; /* range 0-255 */

data1 = (var & 0x0F);      /* range 0-15 */
data2 = (var & 0xF0) >> 4; /* range 0-15 */
```

Comment: You should add a precision on *store 2 numbers in range **0-15**,* because OP asked for 2 numbers in range **0-127**...